# Update data on mysql using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to send the id of an image when a user click on it using ajax. Then in the update.php file I'd like to update the id of the image. I'm new on ajax, so I'm not able to figure out my error.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.show_people_image .love').on('click', function() {

     var id = $(this).attr('id');
     var idpage = "<?php echo $id ?>";
    var sVar1 = encodeURIComponent(id);
    var sVar2 = encodeURIComponent(idpage);
    var sVar3 = "<?php echo $_SESSION['aaa'] ?>";
    var sVar4 = "<?php echo $_SESSION['bbb'] ?>";

     if (sVar1 == sVar2) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "update.php",
        data: {lid:sVar1, ml:sVar3, mem:sVar4},
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            },
        error: function () {
        alert('error');
        }  
     });    
     } 
});
});
```

The update.php file is:

```
if (isset($_POST['lid']) AND isset($_POST['ml']) AND isset($_POST['mem'])) {

include 'models/connexion_sql.php';


$loveid = $_POST['lid'];

if ($_POST['ml']) {
$str = $_POST['ml'].','.$loveid;
}
else {
$str = $loveid;
}


$sql = 'UPDATE users SET myl= :myl WHERE email = :email';
$req = $bdd->prepare($sql);
$req->bindParam(':email', $_POST['mem'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$req->bindParam(':myl', $str, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$req->execute();

echo $str;

}
```

If I put an echo in the upload.php file before the `prepare($sql)` the request is successful, otherwise the request fails.

Comment: nothing wrong with the ajax....put your html code

Comment: I fix the problem but I don't know why it was wrong. Before my update.php file was in the folder models. So, my url was url: "models/update.php". Only putting the update.php file in the localhost folder the program work. Someone know what caused this error? Note that I checked if the ajax request was sent in the correct file by putting an echo in update.php.

Comment: it may be possible that some how database table acquire lock and which cause for it